# Retrieving a row value based on other columns value using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have three data tables that basically contain the following data:

table 1:

```
ID      FContractID     | WaitingTime
1   |   1       |       85
2   |   1       |       98
3   |   1       |       122
4   |   1       |       45
5   |   1       |       234
6   |   1       |       101
```

etc.

Table 2:

```
PricingCriterionItemId  PricingCriterionName        PricingCriterionUnit
1                   |   WaitingTimeMax          |   min
2                   |   WaitingTimePeriod       |   min
3                   |   WaitingTimeOverdue      |   €/period
4                   |   OverDuePriceMax         |   €
```

Table 3:

```
PricingCriterionId      ContractID      PricingCriterionItemId      PricingCriterionValue
1                   |   1           |   1                       |   70
2                   |   1           |   2                       |   30
3                   |   1           |   3                       |   30,00
4                   |   1           |   4                       |   120,00
```

I want to add to the table 1 a column that contains waiting time cost. The waiting time cost would be calculated like

```
WaitingTimeCost = min(((WaitingTime - WaitingTimeMax) / WaitingTimePeriod) * WaitingTimeOverdue, OverDuePriceMax)
```

I can easily join tables 2 and 3 into one table:

Table 4

```
PricingCriterionId      ContractID      PricingCriterionName        PricingCriterionValue       PricingCriterionUnit
1                   |   1           |   WaitingTimeMax          |       70                      |   min
2                   |   1           |   WaitingTimePeriod       |   30                      |   min
3                   |   1           |   WaitingTimeOverdue      |   30,00                   |   €/period
4                   |   1           |   OverDuePriceMax         |   120,00                  |   €
```

Is it possible using linq to assign a column's value on a certain row using other columns value?

Something like

```
  var result = from WaitingData in table1
                join PricingCriteria in table4 
                on WaitingData.ContractId equals PricingCriteria.ContractId
                let WaitingTimeMax = (select PricingCriterionValue from table4 where PricingCriterionName = "WaitingTimeMax")
                let ...
                let WaitingTimeCost = min(((WaitingTime - WaitingTimeMax) / WaitingTimePeriod) * WaitingTimeOverdue, OverDuePriceMax)
                select new
                {
                    ID,
                    WaitingTimeCost
                }
```

How to formulate this properly using linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do everything in the database query.
Database is only IO device, which responsible only for reading and writing data.

Load all required data and calculate.

```cs
var contractsId = waitingData.Select(data => data.ContractId).ToList();
var pricingCriterias = table4.Where(criteria => contractsId.Contains(criteria.ContractId)
                             .ToLookup(criteria => criteria.ContractId);

var maxWaitingTime = 
    pricingCriterias.SelectMany(group => group)
                    .Where(criteria => criteria.PricingCriterionName = "WaitingTimeMax")
                    .Max(criteria => criteria.PricingCriterionValue);

foreach (var waitingItem in waitingData)
{
    // Calculate others waiting values

    var waitingPerPeriod = (WaitingTime - maxWaitingTime) / WaitingTimePeriod);
    var waitingPrice = waitingPerPeriod * WaitingTimeOverdue;
    var WaitingTimeCost = Math.Min(waitingPrice, OverDuePriceMax)
}
```

Below example with `DataTables`.
However `DataTable` is heavy and not strongly typed data structure and as developer it takes more time to deal with it.

Instead transform data in `DataTable` to the plain strong typed objects with descriptive property names - you will get IntelliSense for free ;)

```cs
var contractsId = 
    waitingData.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => row.Field<int>("ContractId"))
               .ToList();
var pricingCriterias = 
    table4.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(row => contractsId.Contains(row => row.Field<int>("ContractId"))
          .ToLookup(row => row.Field<int>("ContractId"));

var maxWaitingTime = 
    pricingCriterias.SelectMany(group => group)
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("PricingCriterionName") = "WaitingTimeMax")
                    .Max(row => row.Field<int>("PricingCriterionValue"));

foreach (var waitingItem in waitingData)
{
    // Calculate others waiting values

    var waitingPerPeriod = (WaitingTime - maxWaitingTime) / WaitingTimePeriod);
    var waitingPrice = waitingPerPeriod * WaitingTimeOverdue;
    var WaitingTimeCost = Math.Min(waitingPrice, OverDuePriceMax)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabio! How should I change the code when waitingData, table4 etc. are datasets? Currently I get an error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ContractId' and no extension method 'ContractId' accepting a first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found" for var pricingCriterias = table4....

Comment: @MarkkuRintala, check updated answer, I strongly suggest to load data into objects instead of DataTables.